# Flexbox: Divs are placing beside each other rather than below

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating a basic portfolio webpage. I have created the sidebar successfully and also the hero image. The two divs that are supposed to be below the hero image are displayed to the right of it instead.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">

        <div id="side-bar-left">

            <div id="contents-left">

                <div id="overlay">

                    <p id="logo">CS</p>

                    <hr class="mini-underline">

                    <div id="links-container">

                        <a class="link" href="#">Welcome</a><br>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Project One</a><br>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Project Two</a><br>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Project Three</a><br>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Contact</a><br>

                    </div>

                    <img id="setting-icon" src="img/settings.png" onclick="openSettings()">

                    <div id="settings-container">

                        <img src="img/arrow.png" id="arrow-icon" onclick="closeSettings()">

                        <p id="ss-button" onclick="removeSS()">Smooth Scroll</p>
                        <p id="hs-button" onclick="hideSB()">Hide Sidebar</p>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

            <div id="hero">

                <div id="hero-overlay">

                </div>

            </div>

        <div id="picture-box">

            <div id="picture-container">

                <div id="picture-overlay">

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="project-one-container">

        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-box;
    display: box;

    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
}

/* ####################### Sidebar stuff ####################### */

    #side-bar-left {
        width: 150px;
        background-color: white;
        -ms-flex: 0 150px;
        -webkit-box-flex:  0;
        -moz-box-flex:  0;
        -ms-box-flex:  0;
        box-flex:  0;  
    }

        #contents-left {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;

            height: 100vh;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: white;

            overflow: hidden;

            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

            #overlay {
                width: 150px;
                height: 0px;

                background-color: rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.7);
            }

/* ####################### Content area ####################### */

/* ####################### Hero image ####################### */

    #hero {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
        align-items: center;

            background-image: url("img/swirl_pattern.png");
            background-attachment: fixed;
    } /* rgb(27, 188, 155);*/

        #hero-overlay {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50vh;

            background-color: rgba(27, 188, 155, 0.8);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
            align-items: center;
        }

    #picture-box {
        height: 25vh;
        width: 100%;

        background-color: #ecedec;
        float: left;
    }

        #about-container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;

            background-color: black;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }

            #picture-container {
                height: 250px;
                width: 250px;

                border-radius: 50%;
                background-color: white;
            }

                #picture-overlay {
                    No styling as of yet
                }

/* ####################### Project one page ####################### */

    #project-one-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150vh;

        background-color: red;
    }
```

[What it's supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1NnE.png)

[What it looks like now (wrong)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kimrz.png)

Comment: project one have to be on the side? or under?

Comment: (top) Hero image ->  picture box -> project one (bottom). Below one another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put the tree in one more div in this case  now you just have to look with the margin and padding the way you want it to be

```css
   
  body{
     margin:0px;
   }

  #wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;

    /*display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-box;
    display: box;

    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;*/
}

/* ####################### Sidebar stuff ####################### */

    #side-bar-left {
        width: 182px;
        background-color: white;
        -ms-flex: 0 150px;
        -webkit-box-flex:  0;
        -moz-box-flex:  0;
        -ms-box-flex:  0;
        box-flex:  0;  
    }

        #contents-left {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;

            height: 100vh;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: white;

            overflow: hidden;

            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

            #overlay {
                width: 150px;
                height: 0px;

                background-color: rgba(56, 56, 56, 0.7);
            }

/* ####################### Content area ####################### */

/* ####################### Hero image ####################### */

    #hero {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
        align-items: center;

            background-image: url("img/swirl_pattern.png");
            background-attachment: fixed;
    } /* rgb(27, 188, 155);*/

        #hero-overlay {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50vh;

            background-color: rgba(27, 188, 155, 0.8);
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center; /* align horizontal */
            align-items: center;
        }

    #picture-box {
        height: 250px;
        width: 100%;

        background-color: #ecedec;
        /*float: left;*/
    }

        #about-container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;

            background-color: black;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }

            #picture-container {
                height: 250px;
                width: 250px;

                border-radius: 50%;
                background-color: white;
            }

                #picture-overlay {
                    No styling as of yet
                }

/* ####################### Project one page ####################### */

    #project-one-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150vh;

        background-color: red;
    }
   .test{
       width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

        <div id="side-bar-left">

            <div id="contents-left">

                <div id="overlay">

                    <p id="logo">CS</p>

                    <hr class="mini-underline">

                    <div id="links-container">

                        <a class="link" href="#">Welcome</a><br>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Project One</a><br>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Project Two</a><br>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Project Three</a><br>
                        <a class="link" href="#">Contact</a><br>

                    </div>

                    <img id="setting-icon" src="img/settings.png" onclick="openSettings()">

                    <div id="settings-container">

                        <img src="img/arrow.png" id="arrow-icon" onclick="closeSettings()">

                        <p id="ss-button" onclick="removeSS()">Smooth Scroll</p>
                        <p id="hs-button" onclick="hideSB()">Hide Sidebar</p>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
<div class="test">

          <div id="hero">

                <div id="hero-overlay">

                </div>

            </div>

        <div id="picture-box">

            <div id="picture-container">

                <div id="picture-overlay">

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="project-one-container">

        </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have an issue, the layout is correct but now there is a huge white space on the right side of the page. The divs are set to 100% but they are not increasing to that space,

Comment: .test{
      width:100%;
    }

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you. I assigned 100% width to the test div after doing this the divs extend off the page and creates a scroll.

Comment: that is normal because your sidebar is fixed i did not think at that i changed a bit yhe codehave a look at it

Comment: Okay I used the calc function in CSS to avoid the issue. Thanks again!